# python setup of control logic for multiple steps

Tags: python, python-3.x

What would be the best way to implement logic to handle scenarios where control logic should evaluate a prior steps output to determine if the next step should be invoked?

For example, say we are making a request using the requests library. I am expecting a key to exist in the first call's response payload, but it may not exist. So how would I say that we try / run the second try block only if the first one did not throw an exception? I believe I could set a global variable somewhere, like `exception_thrown = FALSE`, and add an if statement to evaluate if this is true, but is there a more performant way to write this control logic? There may be more than 1 additional step after the first http call, but these should only be made if the previous try did not fail.

```
try:
   response = requests.get('https://website.com').json()
   if 'key_named_amount_due' in response:
      print('key exists')
      key_for_future_call = response['key_named_amount_due']
except Exception as error:
   print('key did not exist')


try:
   response = requests.get('https://website.com/key=' + key_for_future_call).json()
except Exception as error:
   print(error)
```

Comment: You can use a Boolean `success` variable or simply just use them in the same try block (first one is the better option).

Comment: You could start with checking the response code before using `.json()` and using `.get()` to retrieve the keys.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama right, so having a global variable with True or False, and evaluating this variable in a future try block?

Comment: @KlausD. true, but you can't always rely on the http response code as a measure of success. An API could return 200, while there is an error message.

Comment: Yes. You would validate it before the try block, as your question states though.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `print`ing the error, you should raise an exception and let the calling scope handle it. That way, the function can continue as if it's on the happy path and let the calling scope handle any errors.

```py
import requests

class ValidationFailedError(Exception):
  pass

def handle_get(url):
    resp = requests.get(url).json()
    if 'key_named_amount_due' not in response:
        raise ValidationFailedError('key_named_amount_due not in response')
    key = resp['key_named_amount_due']
    try:
        resp = requests.get(f"{url}/key={key}").json()
    except Exception as e:
        raise ValidationFailedError("failed to get key " + key) from e
```